# Make if logic work to display php variable in custom HTML title

Tags: php, html, if-statement, html-title

I am trying to incorporate logic into my website so that the `$customTitle` is working with the `$nav1` variable. Below is how the page in question is structured.

```php
<?
    $customTitle = "$nav1 | Example.com";
    include_once("_common.php");
    include_once(G5_PATH."head.php");
?>
```

Currently, the HTML title is just showing as  `| Example.com` so `$nav1` is not being included.

I have a switch statement in `head.php` but because that is loaded after (needs to be) it doesn't actually get the data. Below is an example of that switch statement.

```php
switch($gm_code){
    case "pd01" : $nav1 = "Category 1"; break;
    case "pd02" : $nav1 = "Category 2"; break;
    case "pd03" : $nav1 = "Category 3"; break;
    case "pd04" : $nav1 = "Category 4"; break;
    case "pd05" : $nav1 = "Category 5"; break;
}
```

So with this said, the final title would be `Category 1 | Example.com`.

I have tried to implement logic into this by using an `if` statement that looks at `$gm_code` and gives `$nav1` different values based on that code. Below is an example of that.

```php
<?
    if ($gm_code == "pd01") {
        $nav1 = "Category 1";
    }
    $customTitle = "$nav1 | Example.com";
    include_once("_common.php");
    include_once(G5_PATH."head.php");
?>
```

How can I make this logic make sense and include the `$nav1` variable so that it reflects the correct category name in the HTML `<title>`?

Edit:

I cannot just switch the order because it then defaults to the title in `head.php` which uses `<title><?php echo $g5_head_title; ?></title>`. I have incorporated the following `if` logic to make `$customTitle` work, do I have to switch this up to allow the order to change?

```php
if (isset($customTitle)) {
  $g5['title'] = $customTitle;
  $g5_head_title = $customTitle;
} else if (!isset($g5['title'])) {
  $g5['title'] = $config['cf_title'];
  $g5_head_title = $g5['title'];
}
else {
  $g5_head_title = $g5['title'];
  $g5_head_title .= " | ".$config['cf_title'];
}
```

Comment: `<?` short opening tags is very bad practise and you should be using `<?PHP` opening tags for the code block

Comment: You need to include `head.php` *before* you use the `$nav1` variable in `$customTitle`

Comment: You need to ensure that `$gm_code` has been set before running either `switch` or `if` Without that set both are useless

Comment: @RiggsFolly See edit in question.

Comment: Which script is that added code in?

Comment: @Barmar It's in `header.sub.php` which is being called by `_common.php`

Comment: Then you have to move `_common.php` down as well.

Comment: If you are struggling with include order and conflicting code, ie. you're iterating one long procedure with criss-cross dependencies, then stop including files with side-effects, and instead wrap your stuff in functions that you call in the necessary order, and build your output and echo it in one go, instead of having echo statements all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Move `head.php` up so you set `$nav1` before you try to use it in the value of `$customTitle`.

```
<?
    include_once(G5_PATH."head.php");
    $customTitle = "$nav1 | Example.com";
    include_once("_common.php");
?>
```

Comment: See edits in question.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do this the page doesn't load at all. `_common.php` needs to be loaded before `head.php` and `head.php` needs to be loaded before `$customTitle` in order for it to work and that way it doesn't know what the variable is.

Comment: Can you add me to a chat by chance? I would really appreciate more help with this. It's been a tough one for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using a specific order combined with `if` logic for all of the dynamic categories. As long as `_common.php` is loaded before the `if` statements and the `$customTitle` is loaded after the `if` statements and before the `head.php`, it works.

```php
<?
    include_once("_common.php");

    if($gm_code == "pd01"){$nav1 = "Category 1";}
    if($gm_code == "pd02"){$nav1 = "Category 2";}
    if($gm_code == "pd03"){$nav1 = "Category 3";}
    if($gm_code == "pd04"){$nav1 = "Category 4";}
    ... etc

    $customTitle = "$nav1 | EXAMPLE.COM";
    include_once(G5_PATH."/_head.php");
?>
```

So for example, if the dynamic page I'm trying to load uses the `$gm_code == "pd01"` to get its content then the `<title>` is shown as `Category 1 | EXAMPLE.COM`.

Comment: does anything in _head.php need the code above its include?  if index.php need common.php and common.php also need head.php please include both head.php and common.php in order